# Chrome transition fires on page load when form element added

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, css-transitions

There seems to be a bug with Google Chrome version 36.0.1985.143 or am I missing something here. Firefox and Safari seem to work as expected.

Checkout a [Demonstration video on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/103906083)

Css transitions seem to fire on document load when a form element is present in the following html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <form></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a simple css file: style.css

```
div {
    -webkit-transition:background-color 2s;
       -moz-transition:background-color 2s;
         -o-transition:background-color 2s;
            transition:background-color 2s;
    width: 188px;
    height: 188px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

The transition stops firing when the `<form></form>` element is removed **or** when the stylesheet rules are placed inline within the head section of the document like so:

```
<style>
    div {
        -webkit-transition:background-color 2s;
           -moz-transition:background-color 2s;
             -o-transition:background-color 2s;
                transition:background-color 2s;
        width: 188px;
        height: 188px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Is this an actual bug, or am I doing something wrong?

P.S: I have no extensions enabled and this behaviour also shows in incognito mode.
Also, this problems shows whether or not the document is simply opened in the browser via a folder or served from an actual apache webserver.

When I recreate the 'bug' from a similar question: [CSS transition defined in external stylesheet causes transition on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385891/css-transition-defined-in-external-stylesheet-causes-transition-on-page-load?rq=1) it seems to be fixed. Untill I changed the transition property to background-color and ofcourse adding the `<form></form>` element..

UPDATE: Seems it's an actual bug in Chrome. Reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167083) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189). Although they will not fix it any time soon. Anyone know a simple (css) hack/fix for this?

UPDATE2: [Another Demo](http://lab.laukstein.com/bug/input)

Comment: What causes the 'transition' in the first place? I think we're missing some CSS.

Comment: I left off the 'cause' of the transition for simplification of the example. We could add an extra rule: `div:hover { background-color: green; }`. Either way, in my browser it now transitions from white to red and when hovered to green.

Comment: Can you demo the problem to us?

Comment: @Paulie_D I've added a video demonstrating the bug: https://vimeo.com/103906083 and links to the actual bug reports for Chrome. Sadly they wont fix it.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest fix is to add a script tag to the page footer with a single space.

```
<script> </script>
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but I added it right before my `</head>` and it's fixed the glitch.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the same issue the whole day. I've found it was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389566/stop-css3-transition-from-firing-on-page-load) and as one of the commenters said - [here](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/). The second one helped me a lot.

The workaround mentioned is to add a *.preload* class to the *body*

```
<body class="preload">
```

which disables all transitions

```
.preload * {
 -webkit-transition: none !important;
 -moz-transition: none !important;
 -ms-transition: none !important;
 -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

and then remove it with JS (jQuery) to restore the transitions:

```
$("window").load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a CSS only solution when using external CSS file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to provide directions to questions which discuss the same issue, but my profile doesn't have enough reputation to allow me to comment on the author's post.

Comment: Tried improving the answer, hope it's better now.

Comment: @BoyanKostov Thank you for sharing your ideas. Personally I don't like needing javascript to make it function properly. But then again it's the only option we have right now. Maybe if we all 'star' this issue [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189) they will actually try and fix it.

Comment: @DanieldeWit Thank you too. I agree 100%. Starred the issue and I hope to see the bug fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and finally decided that the only acceptable solution was to redefine in the style tag the color of the div like this :

```
<style>
    div {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

So the html code is not too dirty and it's a small fix, even though that would be great if they could resolve this bug

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this problem is to use the single space, empty `<script>` fix found in the answer by spencer.sm. However I've found 2 other ways to solve this problem.

1. Place the CSS of the offending element(s) inside a `<style>` tag in the header of your HTML file. The bug only occurs when the CSS is called from an external stylesheet.
2. Place the offending element(s) in a flexbox container. This fixes the bug as well.