# CSS Transitions firing on page load

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm writing a simple website and have pretty much the same issue as described in these two posts:

- [Stop CSS transition from firing on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389566/stop-css-transition-from-firing-on-page-load)
- [Chrome transition fires on page load when form element added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404206/chrome-transition-fires-on-page-load-when-form-element-added)

The issue is aparent when testing in Brave Browser, not for example in Edge. Although I have not used any `<form>` tag in my site..

Anyway, I can resolve this issue as described in those posts by putting a `<script> </script>` into the footer. My problem is, that I have a bad habit of letting VS Studio format my code with CTRL-K + CTRL + D, which will delete the space between the script tags. Also, copying the footer to a new file will do the same, thus I quite often have to resolve the same issue again and again.

Question now is: Since the linked posts are quite old therefore this issue has been known for quite a long time, is there another - better - way to resolve it?

**Transition Code in Question:**

```css
nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #61625B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 70%;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 15%;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav li {
        width: 125px;
        text-align: center;
    }

.navunderline {
    width: 125px;
    height: 0;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #DAD9D7;
    transition: 500ms;
}

nav a {
    color: #DAD9D7;
}

    nav a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

nav li:hover .navunderline {
    height: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}

#selected .navunderline {
    height: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="content/unternehmen.html">Unternehmen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/referenzen.html">Referenzen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/news.html">News</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: could you provide your code so we can try to debug it?

Comment: @RamondeVries I added the code containing the transition

Comment: i can't seem to replicate the problem in google chrome version 83.0.4103.106

Comment: @RamondeVries so it may seem to be a brave - specific issue?

Comment: i think so yes, but looking at the provided code. there is nothing i see that shouldnt be crossbrowser supported

Comment: OK...the only thing I can see is: the issue goes away as soon as I add the script tag to the footer and the problem is only aparent for the pages, that do not use the `selected` id on one of the listitems (for example the index.html).